# getJSON not working when not using twitter api

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter, jsonp

I just started using getJson today and am a major novice when it comes to json/jquery/ajax stuff.  I have been using: http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/jquery_quickie_unlimited_scroll_using_the_twitter_api.html

The above is a link to a tutorial on creating an infinite scroller that loads several tweets at a time from a json file that it gets from twitter.  When I download that json file and try to use it through localhost or through another hosting service I am unable to get it to work.  looking at chrome networking tools it says the method is get for both, and the status is 200 ok, but the type is application/json for the one on localhost and application/javascript for the working one.

What is happening?  How can i make the script load the file that I have locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getJSON works on JSONP which is an efficient way to communicate cross domain. Please read about it and see the response.

Comment: i dont think it is a problem with json vs jsonp bc all i am changing is this:var url = http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/"
     
+ username + ".json?count="+pageSize+"&page="+currentPage+"&callback=?"; 

to "localhost:80/"+username+".json?count="+pageSize+"&page="+currentPage+"&callback=?"

Comment: for localhost, jquery will make an ajax request where as for twitter it will inject a script in the DOM.

Comment: I just tried putting the json file on a remote web server to no avail.

Comment: which server are you using? apache? may be content type is set mapped to application/json for .json.